# Display players in order relative to a user's position in players array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a card game using AngularJS, and I want to display the players in play order relative to the user's position.  The user's cards are always in a separate div on the bottom of the screen. In order to keep the play order a clockwise direction, it should show the next player first, then the next, then the next, etc.  I am currently using the ng-repeat directive, but this puts player 1 first always.

```
//- The Players 
  .row.center-block
    .col-md-2(ng-if='player.id != p.id ', ng-repeat='p in game.players')
      .row
        .col-md-12
          | {{p.name}}
          span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart(ng-repeat='a in range(p.lives) track by $index')
        .col-md-12
          .card.col-md-1(ng-repeat='card in p.hand track by $index')
            | {{$index}}
```

How can I get one loop of the players array starting from the player object?  My theory is to iterate twice, first everyone in the array after `ng-if='player.id != p.id '`, then everyone before.  Is it also possible to start at a specific index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do this in line, but it turns out easier to do the logic in the javascript.  In a section that processes the game data at a point where I find the user's position (x) in the players array, I put this:

```
$scope.otherPlayers = $scope.game.players.slice(x).concat( $scope.game.players.slice(0,x) );
```

And in my html I changed it to

```
.col-md-2(ng-if='player.id != p.id ', ng-repeat='p in otherPlayers')
```

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) to order the list inside of ng-repeat

remove

```
ng-if='player.id != p.id '
```

add

```
ng-repeat='p in game.players | orderBy: position'
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I don't think I was specific enough in my question. I want the list of players to be in play order relative to the user. Say the user is Player 2, the divs should be "Player 3, Player 4, Player 1"